# Sharing sqlite database between two iphone applications

Tags: iphone

I want to share my sqlite database between two iphone applications
In one application i am reading and writing into that database and in another 
I am reading that data

Can we do this in iphone? And if yes How?

Appreciate any help...

Thanks,
Bhagyashree Dayama

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everybody saying my answer is also NO.. 
but you can achieve the database sharing having a common database at the server and then syncing it on the both local applications.

Answer (score 3):

iPhone Apps are sandboxed.. In simple terms If you create/Install a App, a folder will be created where all your files will be stored. In your case you will have your DB inside that folder.. Your app cannot access anything outside its folder. The same way Another App cannot access your Apps files..

So the answer for your question will be NO..

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no way to access files outside your applications sandbox.