# iPhone: single sqlite database for all apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sharing sqlite database between to iphone applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017187/sharing-sqlite-database-between-to-iphone-applications)

Is it possible to share sqlite database for more than one iPhone applications? If yes then please let me know how.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible. You can't share file between apps, other than copying them to the apps sandbox.

Comment: And please, do not even think about storing your database base64 encoded as a shared keychain password item... yes, I've seen it done. *shudder*

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible. All apps keep sqlite database file in their private application folder, so shared access may not be possible.